# Normal Map ... Format Structure?

Tags: shaders, normal-map

This link ..
[https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/2.79/render/blender_render/textures/properties/influence/bump_normal.html#:~:text=Normal%20maps%20in%20Blender%20store%20a%20normal%20as,%280%20-%20255%29%20to%20Z%20%280.0%20-%201.0%29](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/2.79/render/blender_render/textures/properties/influence/bump_normal.html#:%7E:text=Normal%20maps%20in%20Blender%20store%20a%20normal%20as,%280%20-%20255%29%20to%20Z%20%280.0%20-%201.0%29)

..  States ..

---

Normal maps in Blender store a normal as follows:

```
Red maps from (0 - 255) to X (-1.0 - 1.0)
Green maps from (0 - 255) to Y (-1.0 - 1.0)
Blue maps from (0 - 255) to Z (0.0 - 1.0)
```

Is this accurate ?.. The page was originated with Blender Render from a past version ... I would prefer a more recent version.

---

Is it correct to say Blue is the Y Component of XYZ since the Blender User Sees Y pointing towards the user in the user interface?

I have not found the similar discussion in 2.83 .. yet.

Comment: The camera is aligned along the Z axis, so it is correct to say Blue is the Z component.